# error opening binary file for writing: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'

Tags: c++

I am getting the following output from the following block of code:

```
    //create file for writing
cout << "'" << filename.c_str() << "'" << endl;
    string outfile = filename.append(".bin");
cout << "'" << outfile.c_str() << "'" << endl;
    fstream *binfile;
    binfile->open (outfile.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);
```

prints:

```
'myfile.tmp'
'myfile.tmp.bin'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
  what():  basic_ios::clear
```

What does that error mean, and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
fstream *binfile;
```

You should do this:

```
fstream binfile("filename", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
```

and then call:

```
 binfile << "write here to file";

binfile.close();
```

There is no need for a pointer here.

Comment: Weird. I did that so I could pass it directly to a function. Fixing that, and just passing the reference seemed to make it work.

Comment: @Derek, another problem with your code you didn't `new` your pointer.

Comment: @Derek: You didn't make your pointer point to something, it is still undefined after the declaration.